# Using open data ArcGisMapServer from SITG (Geneva) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem

I would like to use this open data [DSM data source](https://ge.ch/sitg/sitg_catalog/data_details/afeb3bc0-6f80-40df-86da-35a0328a633e/xhtml_raw) QGIS from Geneva, Switzerland municipality. Here is the [data server](https://ge.ch/sitgags2/rest/services/RASTER/MNA_SURFACE/MapServer)

I tried to link it as an ArcGisMapServer source or as WMTS. But when I open the layer properties, QGIS 3.12 (on Linux) cannot determine raster data type.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `https://ge.ch/sitgags2/rest/services/RASTER/MNA_SURFACE/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml` as a WMTS server to my QGIS 3.12 and it loads fine.

[image]